# How to get restlet to follow 301 redirects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, http-redirect

I am currently trying to get a resource which could be behind possible more than one redirect. My code looks like this:

```
        Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
        Context ctx = client.getContext();
        ctx.getParameters().add("followRedirects", "true");      
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(ctx,u); 
        Representation r = cr.get();
```

However redirects are not followed. What am I doing wrong?

This is Restlet 2.1 on Google App Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Series<Parameter> params = ctx.getParameters();
params.add("followRedirects", "true");
ctx.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, though there is a little typo in the first line that should be fixed to make this the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this also using the `ClientResource` class:

```
clientResource.setFollowingRedirects(true);
```

In my case (using Restlet 2.3.9) this seems to be the default behavior.

This method could be also useful in your case:

```
setMaxRedirects(int maxRedirects)
```

> sets the maximum number of redirections that can be automatically followed for a single call.